# Svelte strongly type class of components

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-component

I am working on a component library that has a bit of a twist on how components are grouped. I am grouping components into classes to make using the library simpler for end users. Rather than remembering which named `slots` are available they would instead access the custom slots using a dot notation. For example, a `Card` component could have a `Header`, `Body`, and a `Footer`. In my library I would like to use these componets like so:

```
<Card>
  <Card.Header>I am a Header</Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>I am a Body</Card.Body>
  <Card.Footer>I am a Footer</Card.Footer>
</Card>
```

I have this working currently but I am trying to get this strongly typed as well and that is where I am running into trouble. Here is my file structure:

```
card
  | Card.svelte
  | Body.svelte
  | Header.svelte
  | Footer.svelte
  | index.ts
```

My index.ts file has the following code:

```
import OriginalCard from './Card.svelte';
import Header from './Header.svelte';
import Footer from './Footer.svelte';
import Body from './Body.svelte';

const Card = OriginalCard;
Card.Header = Header;
Card.Body = Body;
Card.Footer = Footer;

export default Card;
```

Header, Body, & Footer all return the following error: `Property 'Header' does not exist on type 'typeof default'. ts(2339)`

When using the component like so:

```
<script lang="ts>
  import Card from '@components/card';
</script>

<Card>
  <Card.Header>I am a Header</Card.Header>
  <Card.Body>I am a Body</Card.Body>
  <Card.Footer>I am a Footer</Card.Footer>
</Card>
```

Header, Body, & Footer all return the following error: `Property 'Body' does not exist on type 'typeof Card__SvelteComponent_'. ts(2339)`

How do I fix these errors?

**EDIT**

After installing this package in another project I noticed two issues that the accepted answer does not solve:

1). `<Card />` returns the following ts error - Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. and breaks all intellisense for the allowable properties.

2). Intellisense does not work with the dot notation. When typing `<Card.` I am not getting suggestions for any of the sub-components and instead it is just showing all components in the entire package.

The desired outcome is to not have the ts errors and not lose intellisense with the package.

I also attempted to extend the `CardStatic` like so:
`interface CardStatic extends OriginalCard` and the same issues continued to persist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend the known type to add the additional properties. Since they are static I would try something like this:

```js
const Card = OriginalCard as CardStatic;
Card.Header = Header;
Card.Body = Body;
Card.Footer = Footer;

export default Card;

export interface CardStatic {
    new(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof OriginalCard>): OriginalCard;
    Header: typeof Header;
    Body: typeof Body;
    Footer: typeof Footer;
}
```

Comment: I am finding that this works in development but when used in production I am running into a few issues: 1). Card gets the following ts error = Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. and 2) VS Code IntelliSense does not recognize the dot notation when using this approach. Any ideas on these two issues?

Comment: For the constructor, you can be more specific in the type (edited the answer). As for the dot notation, there is probably not much you can do except asking the extension developers to handle this case if you are talking about errors in the template part (`<Card.Header ..>`); this is very non-standard so I would not expect them to support this, though.

Comment: That fixed the ts errors. Thank you!